# Как полностью перенести БД 9i на другой ПК?

Tags: sql, oracle

Нужно перенести БД с одного ПК на другой (резервный). ПК1 -старый, ПК2 - новый.

Я устанавливаю с нуля базу данных Oracle 9i на ПК2.

1. Способ перенести БД, в идеале, все пользователи, их привилегии, данные. Вообщем все. Если я с ПК1 перекину файлы БД в путь на БД ПК2. Путь к БД файлам смотрю через `Select name From v$datafile`. Смогу ли я так?
2. С ПК1 перекину в отдельную папку ПК2 БД, а в БД укажу путь, куда теперь смотреть (знаю, есть такой способ).
3. Через SQL Developer сделать SQL файл всей базы и развернуть его на ПК2 не меняя местоположения.

Просто сервер рабочий, не хочу эксперементировать на мануалах, их кучу прочел.

Хотелось бы совета от тех, кто делал.

---

ОС: Windows Server 2003 на обоих ПК.

Comment: Почему вы не воспользуетесь просто экспортом/импортом?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На старой машине (ПК1) сделайте [полный дамп БД](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96652/ch01.htm#1013411):

```
C:\> exp system/pass@orcl full=Y file=c:\dumps\orcl9ifull.dmp log=c:\logs\orcl9ifull.log
```

На новой машине (ПК2) создайте только "чистую" БД, без пользователей, табличных пространств и прочего. Стартуйте БД и загрузите [созданный ранее дамп](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96652/ch02.htm#1656):

```
C:\> imp system/pass@orcl full=Y file=c:\dumps\orcl9ifull.dmp log=c:\logs\orcl9ifull.log
```

Проверьте лог-файл на наличие ошибок. Готово.

Answer (score 1):

[Создание резервных копий с помощью утилиты RMAN (Recovery Manager)](https://oracle-dba.ru/database/backup-and-restore/rman/oracle-rman-backup/)

[Восстановление из резервной копий с помощью утилиты RMAN (Recovery Manager)](https://oracle-dba.ru/database/backup-and-restore/rman/oracle-rman-restore-and-recover/)

На ПК1 сделайте бекап в указаный каталог:

```
RMAN> CONFIGURE CONTROLFILE AUTOBACKUP OFF;
RMAN> backup as COMPRESSED backupset tag DB_BACKUP 
  database format '/tmp/%D_%M_%Y_%u_bkp_%d' plus 
  archivelog format '/tmp/%D_%M_%Y_%u_arc_%d';
RMAN> delete noprompt obsolete;
RMAN> CONFIGURE CONTROLFILE AUTOBACKUP ON;
```

На ПК2 сделайте востановление:

```
RMAN> startup nomount;
RMAN> restore controfile '%path%';
```

где %path% путь к файлу бекапа хранящего control-файлы (обычно первый по времени созданный, во время бекапа, если не угадали перебираем по очереди), например restore controfile '/tmp/20_02_2020_3USJOS2M_BKP_DB';

```
RMAN> alter database mount;
RMAN> catalog start with '%path%';
```

где %path% путь к папке хранящий файлы бекапа, в нашем случае'/tmp/.

```
RMAN> restore database;
RMAN> recover database;
```

Если выдало ошибку, что не хватает сегмента базы данных из следующего архивлога, то восстанавливаем по этот сегмент:

```
RMAN> recover database until sequence=segment;
```

где segment – номер первого сегмента последующего не хватающего архивлога, на который выдало ошибку при выполнении команды recover database;

```
RMAN> alter database open reset logs;
```