# Собрать проект на Visual Studio 2003

Tags: c++, c

Здраствуйте.
Достался проект ранее собранный на Visual Studio 2003.
Изначально поставил себе Visual studio 2003 и перенес проэкт себе на комп.

Не получается собрать по следующей причине.

Не видит файл ,который указан `#include <folder/file.h>`

Есть файл, который подключается через `#include <folder/file.h>`

В папке проекта  include есть не все файлы, они подгружаются к проекту при открытии Visual studio.

На уровень выше от папки проекта так же есть папка include вот в ней как раз все файлы и папки которые нужны для проэкта.

Структура никто не менял.

Пытался добавит в source эти файлы, выдает туже ошибку.
Как указать файлы которых не хватает если их место положение в другом месте.
Где в visual studio 2003 я могу указать откуда подгружать файлы.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло, за что минус?(

Comment: мне не нравится слово проэкт, минус мой

Comment: Извините, а в [этой теме](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1089834/217579) вы ничего не забыли?